# neo4j insert complicated json with relationship between nodes for same

Tags: json, python-3.x, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

This is going to be little complex

I am trying to save a `json` with nested array structure. I have the `json` like below which I am trying to save

[JSON LINK](https://jsonblob.com/16c27433-add2-11e8-b42f-231f14481327)

Is there a possibility to save the above `json` with `cypher` query, because previously I tried with py2neo library for `pyhton`, which is based on model definition, Therefore the above `json` with nested structure will be going to have a dynamic keys a bit.

What I actually tried is, I'm leaving it below

```
query = '''
    CREATE (part:Part PARTJSON) 
    MERGE (part) - [:LINKED_TO] - (general:General GENERALJSON)
    MERGE (general) - [:LINKED_TO] - (bom:Bom BOMJSON )
    MERGE (general) - [:LINKED_TO] - (generaldata:GeneralData GENERALDATAJSON )
.......
'''
```

Is there a possibility to write a `cypher` query to save it in one flash.

If so, can help with possible ideas so that it will be useful for neo4j users with roadblocks.

Thanks in advance.